# Disabled стрелки swiper при первой загрузке

Tags: javascript, vue.js, swiper

При загрузке страницы, стрелки компонента swiper стоят как disabled.
Если ткнуть в слайдер, потягать, тогда стрелки появляются и можно дальше переключать слайды.

**HTML**

```
<div class="swiper-button-prev" v-on:click="prev" slot="button-prev"></div>
<swiper ref="mySwip" class="swipper" :options="swiperOption">
<swiper-slide class="swiper-slide swiper-slide_item" 
v-for="(item, index) in pack" :key="index.id">
<div>
{{item}}
</div>
</swiper-slide>
</swiper>
<div class="swiper-button-next" v-on:click="next" slot="button-next"></div>
```

**Vue.js**

```
    pack: {1,2,3 .....} //какие-нибудь данные
    swiperOption: {
                        slidesPerView: 'auto',
                        navigation: {
                            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
                        },
                    },
-------

            prev() {
                this.$refs.mySwip.swiper.slidePrev(25)
            },
            next() {
                this.$refs.mySwip.swiper.slideNext(25)
            },
```

**css**

```
.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-button-prev {
    transition: opacity .5s;
    top:45%;
    z-index: 999;
}

.swiper-button-disabled {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно кнопки управления находятся внутри контейнера слайда. Но если вам нужен такой вариант их применения, привожу пример.

```js
Vue.use(VueAwesomeSwiper)
new Vue({
     el: '#vueapp',
   components: {

     },
     data: {
     swiperOptionA: {
            pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination'
        },
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
        }
     },
     swiperOptionB: {
        pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
          dynamicBullets: true
        }
     }
     },
   computed: {
      swiperA() {
        return this.$refs.awesomeSwiperA.swiper
      }
    },
    methods: {
        onSetTranslate() {
        console.log('onSetTranslate')
      }
    },
    mounted() {
     // console.log('this is swiper A instance object', this.swiperA, 'B instance', this.swiperB)
    }
    })
```

```css
.swiper-container {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: #eee;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!-- Include stylesheet -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Include the Swiper library -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Swiper JS Vue -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-awesome-swiper@3.1.2/dist/vue-awesome-swiper.js"></script>

<div id="vueapp">
    <swiper ref="awesomeSwiperA" :options="swiperOptionA">
      <!-- slides -->
      <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 1</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 2</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 3</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 4</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 5</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 6</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 7</swiper-slide>
      <!-- Optional controls -->
      <div class="swiper-pagination"  slot="pagination"></div>

    </swiper>
    
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    
    
</div>
```

Comment: А если мне нужно разместить стрелки за пределами контейнера плеера?

Comment: все зависит от условий, но один из способов, это убрать дата-атрибут - slot у элементов управления и задать им уникальные селекторы, которые передать в параметры swiper

Comment: В ответ вставил примерный вариант использования, извиняюсь за оформление) И да - я селекторы кнопок не изменял, но если у вас несколько слайдеров на странице, необходимо задавать уникальные селекторы, чтобы не было конфликта между слайдерами.

Comment: Николай, можете подсказать, как задавать уникальны селекторы, для слайдеров?
Никогда раньше с таким не сталкивался.
Большое спасибо за столь подробный ответ!

Comment: Вам просто нужно задать классы для кнопок управления таким образом, чтобы названия этих классов были уникальные. Способ создания зависит от вашего решения, если ваши слайдеры формируются как статичные - то достаточно просто создать для них уникальный буквенно-цифровой набор текста.